# Iterators for a string class

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I'm creating a string class(project school) and I down to the last create iterators for it, so my problem is I don't know where to start I supposed that the begin and the end but how are those implemented. here is the code so far:

```
class StringsTest {


public:
std::tr1::shared_ptr<char* > word; 
char* data;
int size;
int final;
int itSize;
StringsTest();
StringsTest(const StringsTest& orig);
virtual ~StringsTest();
StringsTest(char* strings);
StringsTest& swap( StringsTest& str2 );
int push_back(char a);
char pop_back();
int insert(int where, char what);
int erase(int where);
friend void operator<<(std::ostream& Ostr, const StringsTest& st);
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& Istr, StringsTest& st);
char &operator[](int i);
int sizes();
int check();
stringIte& begin();
stringIte& end();



private:

protected:
};

#endif  /* STRINGPROJ_H *

//#endif    /* STRINGSTEST_H */

class stringIte {
public:
stringIte();
~stringIte();
```

And the begining:

```
stringIte& StringsTest::begin() {
try {


} catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << " an error has ocurred " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
}

stringIte& StringsTest::end() {
try {



} catch (std::exception e) {

    std::cout << "nope " << e.what() << std::endl;

}
}
```

I have this class how do I implement iterator begin(). Thanks.

Comment: -1 for no showing any research effort. You can study `std::string` and see how it implements iterators

Comment: I am reading it this is another, area to cover, if I don't understand something I come here. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you don't want to return the iterators by reference. Return them by value.

An iterator is like a pointer to an element of a collection (to a character in the string, in your case). One way of implementing them would be to just do `typedef char *stringIte;` and use raw pointers as your iterators (they provide all the functionality necessary). `begin()` would then return `data` and `end()` would return `data + size` (assuming `data` is the pointer to the string data and `size` is its length without the terminating `NUL`.

A more fancy way could be a simple structure which could e.g. contain a `StringTest*` and an `int`, and return the appropriate character from the string on derefernce.

Comment: `end()` should return `data + size`, not `data + size + 1`.  One of the nice things about the half open interval is that `end() - begin() == size()`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks, fixed. I over-thought the terminating `NUL` scenario.

Comment: @Pedro311 What do you mean "STL way"? `char*` models `RandomAccessIterator`, so it does all an STL random access iterator does. Also, see the "more fancy way" in my answer.

Comment: If you look into the latest [ISO C++ draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) into sections [iterator.iterators] and following, you'll see all operations an "STL iterator" must support. You'll find `char*` supports them all.

Comment: @Angew btw, you may want to update your bookmark to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf ;)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thanks. I got the link from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#cite_ref-5), I trusted them when they said it's the latest.

Answer (score 0):

You already have `operator[]`.  The simplest solution would be
for the iterator to maintain a pointer to the `StringTest`
object and an index, and have it use the `[]` operator on the
string when it needs to.  This has an additional advantage as it
allows easy error checking.

More efficient implementations are possible if the iterator
knows something of the internals of the string class.  If the
actual characters are in a contiguous array, for example, the
iterator can consist of a single pointer (or even be a typedef
to `char*`).